# send file from node server to react client

Tags: node.js, express, file, fetch-api

i'm trying to fetch file name from react client to my node server, then to send the file i asked according to the name.
it looks like it fall in the client side, but i'm not sure where the problem is.
the file type can be PDF or any kind of photo file.
thanks

this is the relevant code in react:

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('/documents/getDoc', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ selectedDoc }),// sending the file name
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log('file: ',res);
        setDoc(res); // i want to save here the file

      });
  },[selectedDoc])
```

this is the sever code in node:

```
router.post('/getDoc', (req, res) => {
  const body = [];
  req.on('data', chunk => {
    body.push(chunk);
  });
  req.on('end', async () => {
    const obj = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(obj);
    // const list = await getOpenDocList(obj.selectedCus)
    // res.end(JSON.stringify(list))
    // res.sendFile(__dirname + '../documents/' + obj.name)

        // Use path.join to create the correct file path
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../documents/', obj.name);

        // Use res.sendFile to send the file
        res.sendFile(filePath, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Error sending file:', err);
            res.status(404).send('File not found');
          }
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: `res.json()` is for JSON. You want [res.blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob).

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the file once you have it client-side?

Comment: hi thanks for the explanation. I want to display the file, and give the user fields in which data can be filled from the file.
but is i want to display the file what am i supposed to do with this blobUrl?

i have a component, that when i giv it file object, it display it: 
`import myFile from './hesh.pdf';`
...
`<PdfViewerComponent document={myFile} />`

Answer (score 0):

First, your manual handling of the request body is unnecessary (though perhaps a good learning exercise).

Express has [built-in JSON request body parsing middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)

```js
app.use(express.json());

// ...

router.post('/getDoc', (req, res) => {
  const obj = req.body; //  JSON body is already parsed

  // ...
});
```

You just need to ensure you send the request with the correct headers

```js
fetch('/documents/getDoc', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ selectedDoc }),
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
})
```

---

Your client-side code is using `res.json()` which is only appropriate if the response is a JSON formatted string.

To receive a binary (file) object, you'll need to use [res.blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob). With that you can create temporary URLs to display, link or download

```js
fetch("/documents/getDoc", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({ selectedDoc }),
  headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
})
  .then((res) => (res.ok ? res.blob() : Promise.reject(res)))
  .then((blob) => {
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // now do something with the URL
  });
```